about shear strength of soil

A direct shear test on specimens of fine sand gave the following results
Normal stress (lb/ft2 ) 2100 , 3700 , 4500
Shearing stress (lb/ft2 ) 970 , 1700 , 2080
Determine: (i) the angle of internal friction of the soil, and (ii) shear strength of the soil at a depth of 15 ft
from the ground surface. The specific gravity of solids is 2.65, void ratio 0.7 and the ground water table is
at a depth of 5 ft from the ground surface. Assume the soil above ground watar table is saturated.


what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a homework question with no attempt to solve it.
